# Cannot figure out how to add boundaries to this code

Tags: c#, arrays, conditional-statements

I am having issues trying to insert a boundary that the user input must obey. This program is supposed to let the user input 7 integers between **0-100**. The 0-100 boundary is supposed to **keep the user from inputting negative integers while keeping the numbers limited to 99**. The integers the user inputs are stored in an array and if he/she inputs a duplicate input, the condition removes the inserted illegal input and asks the user again. This is hard because logically do not know how to implement such a condition in the code I have already made.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class ArrayInput
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int input; //user input variable
            int[] array; //declared array
            array = new int[7]; //array has a given one dimensional quantity
            Console.WriteLine("This program will ask you to input 7 numbers only, no duplications.");


                for (input = 0; input <= 6; input++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter your numbers.");
                        array[input] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //input can only take in integers
                    }

                    catch (FormatException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("That input will not work, it is set to 0 and removed. Please try again.");
                        --input;
                    }

                    while (array.Take(input).Contains(array[input])) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("This is a duplicated input, please try again.");
                        --input; //this removes the input that was wrong from the array
                    }

                     Console.WriteLine("Your last entered integer: " + array[input]); //print out the element so that user can verify

                }

                for (input = 0; input <= 6; input++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou entered these: " + array[input]); //prints out all elements inputted from algorithm above
                }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Where would I put the 0-100 boundary condition? Also this is a mock-up, so no this is not the final code, therefore please do not be negative about this. I just need ideas.

Comment: Look into recursion...

Comment: using a class with methods?